# An appended element keeps appending (infinitely ) after scroll, it should append only once

Tags: jquery, scroll, append

I already appended a div to a form (after scroll), my problem is that this div just keeps appearing infinitely when the user scroll.

You can see this div on this website http://www.cimacademico.ml/online/cursos-online/curso-detalle-ejemplo/, is the closing x that appears at the corner of the form, after you scroll 800px.

```js
jQuery(function() {
jQuery(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll2 = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
    if (scroll2 >= 800) {      
        jQuery(".form-curso-detalle").append("<div class='closeform'>X</div>");
        jQuery(".closeform").click(function() {
        jQuery(this).parent().fadeOut(100);
        })
    } else {
        jQuery('.closeform').empty().remove();
        jQuery(".form-curso-detalle").fadeIn(100);
    }
});
```

});

I`m aiming to achieve that the div only appends one time. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Thanks Rory, I added the if statement, but it doesn't solve the problem

Comment: Like rory said, you're executing one of the if/else blocks on every scroll event.

Comment: Because you are saying add the div on every scroll of 800 or more. You should say IF div not already appended and scroll of 800 or more THEN add the div.

Comment: @user2965583 thanks for updating. The issue is because the `scroll` event fires *for every pixel you scroll*. Therefore you're calling `append()` for every pixel scrolled. You need to either check the element doesn't already exist before appending it, or hide/show it in either side of your condition

Comment: Thanks Roy I`ll try that. Anyway, Even so, any code would be wellcome!

Answer (score 0):

Solveed it! Thanks Nawed and rory!

```
jQuery(function() {
jQuery(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll2 = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
    if (scroll2 >= 800) {      
        if(jQuery('.closeform').length == 0) {
        jQuery(".form-curso-detalle2").append("<div class='closeform'>X</div>");
        }
        jQuery(".closeform").click(function() {
        jQuery(this).parent().fadeOut(100);
        })
    } else {
        jQuery('.closeform').empty().remove();
        jQuery(".form-curso-detalle2").fadeIn(100);
    }
});
});
```

Comment: You are unnecessarily creating a million click handlers because the code is inside the scroll handler. Please review my answer for a solution.

Comment: I reviewed it, maybe i'm missing something but, it didn't worked.

Comment: What didn't work? It does not add the div anymore? it adds too many divs? the close button doesn't work? please explain.

Answer (score 0):

On top of checking before appending you should also not create an event handler on every bit of scrolling. Move the click event handler outside the scroll handler and attach it to body.

```
jQuery(function() {
   jQuery(window).scroll(function() {    
     var scroll2 = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
     if (scroll2 >= 800 && jQuery('.closeform').length == 0) {
        jQuery(".form-curso-detalle2").append("<div class='closeform'>X</div>");
     } else {
        jQuery('.closeform').empty().remove();
        jQuery(".form-curso-detalle2").fadeIn(100);
     }
   });

   //this handler is added to body so that it works 
   //even if the element doesn't already exists
   jQuery("body").on("click", ".closeform", (function() {
      jQuery(this).parent().fadeOut(100);
   })
});
```